# XSLT Firefox Problem

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt

I would greatly appreciate if someone could shed light as to why this http://www.binarymark.com/Products/BiorhythmCalculator/bioreport.aspx?day=1&month=1&year=1971
renders perfectly in Opera, IE, Chrome, but fails completely in Firefox 3.1 and 3.5 beta 4?
What's wrong with XML/XSLT?

Thanks.

Comment: may be some code would help..... in Firefox it keeps loading for a long time.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the same thing. All other browsers load it very quickly. Some code? Well its available in the output... just use IE and select view page source (I am not sure if I can post here both long xslt and xml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very strange indeed. The only thing I see when I run it is 'BinaryMark'.

Seeing as the only place this appears in the output code is in the javascript at the bottom of the template I changed it to the following and it works fine:

```
<p align="center" class="text">
  This Report was generated by 
  <a href="{Report/@GeneratorURL" target="_blank">
  <xsl:value-of select="Report/@Generator"/></a> on
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something to do with the face that the XML is not valid when validated against the XSD file specified in the XML (http://www.binarymark.com/Products/BiorhythmCalculator/bioreport/report.xsd)?

For example, the XSD specifies only "Male" or "Female" are valid for the Gender element, but in the XML it contains "NA".

Perhaps you could remove the reference to the XSD schema from the XML, to see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks. But as it turns out JS was the problem, and this small mismatch is fine (apparently ignored).